# Typhoon + Swift: Crash when using run-time arguments

Tags: ios, swift, code-injection, swift2, typhoon

I'm currently trying out Typhoon to add Dependency Injection to my app which is right now half Swift, half legacy Objective-C. I'm trying to instantiate a view controller from a Storyboard in my assembly but am running in the crash below. I read here https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/293 that using NSString would solve the issue but as you can see below I already did that and its not quite helping ... Any ideas?

```
dynamic func typhoonStoryboard(name: NSString) -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TyphoonStoryboard.self, configuration: { (definition) -> Void in
            definition.useInitializer("storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:", parameters: { (initializer) -> Void in
                initializer.injectParameterWith(name)
                initializer.injectParameterWith(self)
                initializer.injectParameterWith(NSBundle.mainBundle())
            })
        })
    }

 dynamic func viewController(withStoryboardName storyboardName: NSString, storyboardIdentifier: NSString) -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withFactory(self.typhoonStoryboard(NSString(string: storyboardName)), selector: "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:", parameters: { (method) -> Void in
            method.injectParameterWith(NSString(string: storyboardIdentifier))
        }, configuration: { (definition) -> Void in

        })
    }
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Like you see I'm already doing the workaround with NSString but it still crashes with the following exception exception...

```
2015-09-15 09:26:32.484 MyApp[64855:5393006] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You can't call a method on the runtime argument being passed in. It has to be passed in as-is'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae0ff65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a42edeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae0fe9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   MyApp                            0x00000001052282b3 -[TyphoonInjectionByRuntimeArgument forwardingTargetForSelector:] + 67
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad65c4e ___forwarding___ + 158
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad65b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bff54b3 _TTSf4g_d___TFSSCfMSSFT12_cocoaStringPSs9AnyObject__SS + 131
    7   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010bfbce33 _TFSSCfMSSFT12_cocoaStringPSs9AnyObject__SS + 19
    8   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010c3e0af9 _TToFE10FoundationCSo8NSStringcfMS0_FT6stringS0__S0_ + 41
    9   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010c3e0a3a _TFE10FoundationCSo8NSStringCfMS0_FT6stringS0__S0_ + 58
    10  MyApp                            0x0000000104cc890d _TFC8MyApp22ViewControllerAssembly14viewControllerfS0_FT18withStoryboardNameCSo8NSString20storyboardIdentifierS1__PSs9AnyObject_ + 157
    11  MyApp                            0x0000000104cc90cf _TToFC8MyApp22ViewControllerAssembly14viewControllerfS0_FT18withStoryboardNameCSo8NSString20storyboardIdentifierS1__PSs9AnyObject_ + 79
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010acfe85c __invoking___ + 140
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010acfe6ae -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad8f016 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    15  MyApp                            0x000000010520ea76 objc_msgSend_InjectionArguments + 454
    16  MyApp                            0x000000010520e83e -[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder definitionForKey:] + 254
    17  MyApp                            0x000000010520e61f -[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder populateCacheWithDefinitionForKey:] + 111
    18  MyApp                            0x000000010520e01b -[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder builtDefinitionForKey:args:] + 203
    19  MyApp                            0x000000010520df20 -[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder buildDefinitionForKey:] + 64
    20  MyApp                            0x000000010520de43 __49-[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder populateCache]_block_invoke + 163
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad6f0df __51-[__NSSetM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 79
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad6efea -[__NSSetM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 202
    23  MyApp                            0x000000010520dd69 -[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder populateCache] + 185
    24  MyApp                            0x000000010520dc1a -[TyphoonAssemblyDefinitionBuilder builtDefinitions] + 74
    25  MyApp                            0x000000010520a976 -[TyphoonAssembly definitions] + 54
    26  MyApp                            0x000000010520ff1a -[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory registerAllDefinitions:] + 90
    27  MyApp                            0x000000010520fd78 -[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory buildAssembly:] + 104
    28  MyApp                            0x000000010520fc10 -[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory initWithAssemblies:] + 544
    29  MyApp                            0x000000010520f8b7 +[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory factoryWithAssemblies:] + 87
    30  MyApp                            0x00000001052340d2 +[TyphoonStartup requireInitialFactory] + 194
    31  MyApp                            0x00000001052345ad __60+[TyphoonStartup swizzleSetDelegateMethodOnApplicationClass]_block_invoke + 93
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000108a8825b -[UIApplication _setDelegate:assumeOwnership:] + 51
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000108a93cea _UIApplicationMainPreparations + 1618
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000108a93647 UIApplicationMain + 124
    35  MyApp                            0x0000000104b1f80f main + 111
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c5a492d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typhoon is a fairly typical introspective and reflective type DI container, optimized for Objective-C. (Also works quite well for Swift).

- At startup: Typhoon gather information from all the assemblies on how to build objects
- At runtime: The assembly interface poses in front of the TyphoonComponentFactory which knows how to emit components based on all of those gathered rules.

To obtain a component:

```
Rules parsed on startup->post processing->factory emits built objects
```

Therefore: In the case of runtime arguments we can't invoke any methods on them, or otherwise manipulate them after being passed in, because this would not be relevant to the startup phase when Typhoon builds object instantiation blueprints.

If you declare the runtime argument of type NSString, and the pass it directly without manipulation (rather than `NSString(string: storyboardIdentifier)`), it should work  fine.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! And nice explanation also :)